# How do I set up permissions so that all developers get ALL PRIVILEGES to objects that any of the other developers create?

Tags: postgresql, database-permissions

I want all developers to be able to work with each other's code. When one person creates a table, others should be able to query it directly without permissions needing to be granted.

I thought the way to accomplish this was to create a role `role_developers`, have all developers be members of that role, and then do this:

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON TABLES TO role_developer;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON SEQUENCES TO role_developer;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES IN SCHEMA public GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON FUNCTIONS TO role_developer;
```

My expectation is that setting those default privileges as above means that every new instance of such objects in the public schema will be assigned those privileges to everyone who's a member of that role.

However, even after doing this (logged in as my personal user account, which is also a member of `role_developer`), I'm finding that after I create a new table, my colleagues aren't able to `SELECT` from it.

So obviously I'm missing something. I'm new to pgsql although I'm an experienced SQL Server developer, which is obviously clouding my perspective.

Comment: I would have guessed what you did was correct and am surprised to hear it didn't work.  As a work-around, whenever you all create a new object, can you just assign its owner to role_developer?  `alter table my_new_table owner to role_Developer`

Answer (score 1):

The `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements you show will only affect tables created by the user who ran these statements.

You'll have to run

```
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE someuser ....
```

for all the users that can possible create such objects.

This is annoying, and it still doesn't allow other users to drop or alter tables that I created, because that is restricted to the table owner.

It might be a better setup to have a role created like this:

```
CREATE ROLE object_owner NOINHERIT;
```

and grant that role to all your users.

Then whenever somebody wants to create, alter or drop an object, they first have to do

```
SET ROLE object_owner;
```

Then you only need to run one set of `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` commands for that role.

You can enforce this by granting `CREATE` on the schemas only to `object_owner`.